# PgAdmin 3 @ Ubuntu 14.10: low responsiveness when typing

Tags: 14.10, postgresql, responsiveness

I've been using PostgreSQL and PgAdmin 3 for years without problems so far. Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.10 at new notebook with PgAdmin. The problem is that I have to type very slowly to get the query I want.
E.g. if I type "**select * from users;**" too fast, I get something like "**slct* ro srs;**". (Each time it's different, of course.)
This is very annoying and I'm really stuck with that. Searching on the Internet didn't reveal anything, I don't even know how to debug this.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 (everything updated) 64 bit with 16 GB RAM, SSD and Unity.
Any solution or debugging hints will be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like this might be a bug, if others are using this.  Have you considered possibly filing a bug on the issue and see if many others are able to replicate this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't add a comment to your question and my previous answer was deleted.

I just filled a bug (and copied some of your question) about this: 
[low responsiveness when typing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgadmin3/+bug/1399673)

> by Robert TheSim
>
> Maybe it is a wxWidgets / iBus bug. I fixed it disabling IBus. Go to
>   Language Support and change 'Keyboard input system' from 'IBus' to
>   'None'. Not only I don't experience missing keystrokes anymore, I feel
>   pgAdmin is more responsive globally.
>
> **then logoff your unity/ubuntu session and logon again.**
>
> source: [low responsiveness when typing - comment #5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgadmin3/+bug/1399673/comments/5)

Comment: Thank you. For time being I gave up using pgAdmin. It's not usable as it is now. I tried to send a question to support mailing list, that didn't work either.

Comment: And what are you using? I'm looking for an alternative too.

Comment: Simply psql. In the past I also used DbVisualiser.

Comment: Comment by [robert thesim](http://askubuntu.com/users/373081/robert-thesim): Maybe it is a wxWidgets / iBus bug. I fixed it disabling IBus. Go to Language Support and change 'Keyboard input system' from 'IBus' to 'None' *then logoff your unity/ubuntu session and logon again.* Not only I don't experience missing keystrokes anymore, I feel pgAdmin is more responsive globally.  source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgadmin3/+bug/1399673/comments/5