# Keyboard not working properly in gEdit - Ubuntu 14.10 - Asus 1015 pem

Tags: keyboard, asus, 14.10, keys

Keyboard not working properly in gEdit - Ubuntu 14.10 - Asus 1015 pem

The issue is not happening in Libreoffice or other text area. It is intermittently happening in gEdit. At first, it keeps on lagging while typing, then some keys will totally stopped responding.

I'm not sure if the driver for the keyboard is needed. I haven't try other text editor yet. Again, it is working fine on the browser, libre office, etc.

Thanks for helping. It is my first time installing ubuntu on my netbook.

Comment: Do you have an AMD video card? This happens to me with some gtk apps since i upgraded to 14.10 but i can't find the source of problems

Comment: It happens not for AMD only, I have NVidia and this problem makes gedit useless. Even I beam becomes invisible. The only way to get it back is requesting context menu.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has also been reported for PgAdmin; the given solution seems to fix the problem for Gedit also :

[PgAdmin 3 @ Ubuntu 14.10: low responsiveness when typing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550652/pgadmin-3-ubuntu-14-10-low-responsiveness-when-typing)

> by Robert TheSim
>
> Maybe it is a wxWidgets / iBus bug. I fixed it disabling IBus. Go to Language Support and change 'Keyboard input system' from 'IBus' to 'None'.